# "An error occured when installing puma (3.4.0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, puma

I've been trying to deploy my ruby application for the past few days but I keep getting error after error, one in particular that I'm dealing with is this one :

```
remote:        mini_ssl.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        make: *** [Makefile:245: mini_ssl.o] Error 1
remote:        
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_4e567092/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_4e567092/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/puma-3.4.0/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing puma (3.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          puma
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

so based what the error is saying I went ahead and ran the command :

```
gem install puma -v '3.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

and it worked perfectly fine :

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed puma-3.4.0
Parsing documentation for puma-3.4.0
Done installing documentation for puma after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but I still keep getting the same error saying about puma not installing. I'm not sure what to do at this point and need some help, thanks.

Comment: Seems like OS libraries (SSL) incompatibility issues. Puma 3.x is quite old. Why not upgrade?